# How Can Get the actual Pre Shared Key to Application instead of "*" in Android

Tags: android

I am building application related to WiFi using my Samsung Android Phone.

Am trying to access the pre shered key to my application using WifiConfiguration class provided by Android. The getPreSharedKey() method returns only "*" if key is present and null if the key is absent.I need the actual the pre shared key. How do i obtain it ?

Is there any other method that I can use to get the key ?

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 2):

The pre-shared key is not made available to applications for security reasons.

There is no reason that an application should have access to the pre-shared key. The OS handles connecting to WiFi Networks and thus it is the only part of the system which actually needs the key.

If the app is trying to help connect to a WiFi Network then it only needs to set the key, not retrieve it.